# How do I get historical stock price data from a local exchange using Python?

Tags: python, dataset, prediction

So I am working on a project to build a stock price predictor model. Part of building the model includes data collection from a local exchange, Dar es Salaam Stock Exchange (DSE) to be specific, find the link next to this text: https://dse.co.tz/
Is there any python library that I can use to obtain this data set and use it to train the model?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need a [data subscription](https://data.dse.co.tz/#) to be able to retrieve any historical data from this stock exchange. The website states that they have an API, so you should be able to query this API using a Python library like [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).